# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm having difficulty getting the following to work, all I get from Chrome's Console is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string.

I have tried `tmp = event.keyCode` and changing `tmp` in the `if` statement to `event.keyCode` but I cannot identify the problem.

```js
function showSearching() {
    alert ("Hello World");
}

$('#search').bind('keydown', function() {
    tmp = Number(event.keyCode);
    if ( ( tmp=<"48" && tmp=>"90" ) || ( tmp=<"96" && tmp=>"111" ) || ( tmp=<"186" && tmp=>"222" ) ) {
        showSearching();
    }    
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" type="text">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrong syntax of relational operator in if statement.

change `=> to >=` and `=< to <=`

```
$('#search').bind('keydown', function() {
    tmp = Number(event.keyCode);
    if ((tmp  <= "48" && tmp  >= "90") || (tmp  <= "96" && tmp  >= "111") || (tmp  <= "186" && tmp  >= "222")) {
        showSearching();
    }
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `=<` to `<=`

```
if ( ( tmp<="48" && tmp>="90" )
```